# Функция для вывода вопроса

Tags: delphi

Какой функцией и как можно вывести вопрос, чтобы пользователь мог ответить Да или Нет?

Comment: Кажется, вам стоило бы глубже разобраться с функциями и средой вцелом. Вывод вопроса - дело одно. Нажатие пользователем Да/Нет - другое. Функции - третье.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var
  result: Integer;
...
result := MessageDlg('Вы действительно хотите покинуть игру?', mtInformation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0);
if result = mrYes then Halt;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Yes := (
  Application.MessageBox(
    'Вы действительно хотите то-то или то-то?',
    'Вопрос',
    MB_ICONQUESTION or MB_YESNO
  ) = ID_YES
);
```

Comment: Красиво. Но ради красоты пришлось лишние скобки рисовать...

Comment: Ну, здесь в первую очередь, желание продемонстрировать функцию `MessageBox()`, а стиль кода каждый сам для себя определяет. Я, например, привык все условия заключать в скобки...

Comment: Хм, не вижу здесь условия, только выражение типа Boolean.